# Factorial and Fibonacci functions work, but I can't get the third function to work

Tags: python, function, fibonacci, factorial

```
 def Factorial(n):
    n=int(input("Input a number?"))
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * Factorial(n-1)    
def Fibonacci(num):
    i=0
    present=1
    previous=0
    while i<=num:
            nextterm=present+previous
            present=previous
            previous=nextterm
            i=i+1
            print("The fibonacci number for", i, "is", nextterm)
def CallFibOrFac(s):
    s=input('Fib or Fac?')
    if s == 'Fib':
        num=input('Up to what number?')
        print(Fibonacci(num))
    elif s == 'Fac':
        n=input('What number?')
        print(Factorial(n))   
CallFibOrFac()
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to solve this assignment. I don't understand how I'm supposed to have my defined function CallFibOrFac call the other two functions for solving the Fibonacci or Factorial numbers. Any help/explanation is appreciated. Thanks!

This is the exact prompt that I was left with in class:

> Write a Python program that has 3 Functions:
>
> The first function will be called CallFibOrFac
>
> It will receive a single string as a parameter.
>
> If the string is "Fib" it will call the second function called
>   Fibonacci
>
> If the string is "Fac" it will call the third function called
>   Factorial.
>
> The Second function prints the first 10 numbers in the Fibonacci
>   sequence.
>
> The Third function prints the value of 10 factorial.
>
> We want to make the second and third functions work for cases other
>   than just the first 10 numbers so add a parameter to the Fibonacci
>   function and the Factorial function which will tell it how far to go
>   along the Fibonacci sequence or the Factorial.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
"I can't get [it] to work" is not a problem specification.  Tell us exactly what doesn't work for you, including actual and desired outputs.

Comment: In what way does the third function "not work?" Error message? Wrong output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few errors on your code:

- Your `CallFibOrFac` function receives a string but overwrites it. The task says it will just pass the string, use it as given;
- You are asking for a new input on every iteration of the factorial method, it should be given before the function starts;
- You forgot to convert the string to int before passing it to the Fibonacci Function.

That said, all the corrected functions should be:

Factorial Function:

```
def Factorial(n):
    # Removed the input read
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * Factorial(n-1)
```

Fibonacci Function:

```
# It is working as expected
def Fibonacci(num):
    i=0
    present=1
    previous=0
    while i<=num:
        nextterm=present+previous
        present=previous
        previous=nextterm
        i=i+1
        print("The fibonacci number for", i, "is", nextterm)
```

CallFibOrFac

```
def CallFibOrFac(s):
    # Moved the number detection out of the ifs, since both will use it
    # Note that the task says it will _receive_ the string as parameter, so you don't need to ask here.
    num=int(input('Up to what number?'))
    if s == 'Fib':
        print(Fibonacci(num))
    elif s == 'Fac':
        print(Factorial(num))
```

*Note: There are stuff left to fix and / or improve, I just worked on which might be a problem for you right now (As noted by @abarnert)*

Comment: There’s a few more errors you didn’t fix (e.g., you probably don’t want to print the result of Fibonacci given that it always returns None), but this should be more than enough to get him unstuck.

Comment: That was my goal. Fixing just the errors that might get him stuck, avoiding to rewrite the code as much as I could and just providing a general guidance on what to fix - otherwise I would be doing the task for him

Answer (score -1):

You define `CallFibOrFac` to take an input, but when you run it at the bottom, you don't give it one. Either define the function as `def CallFibOrFac()`, or give it a string input when you run it. The way you have written the script, by asking for the string sequence with `input`, means that you don't need s in the definition of the function. When I get rid of the s in the definition, the script runs just fine for me, but remember that you need to reply with 'Fib' or 'Fac' with marks to declare that they are strings

Also, in the future it would be helpful if you posted the error message you receive

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
def Factorial(n):
    n=int(input("Input a number?"))
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * Factorial(n-1)

def Fibonacci(num):
    i=0
    present=1
    previous=0
    while i<=num:
        nextterm=present+previous
        present=previous
        previous=nextterm
        i=i+1
        print("The fibonacci number for", i, "is", nextterm)

def CallFibOrFac():
    s=input('Fib or Fac?')
    if s == 'Fib':
        num=input('Up to what number?')
        print(Fibonacci(int(num)))
    elif s == 'Fac':
        n=input('What number?')
        print(Factorial(int(n)))

CallFibOrFac()
```

Comment: This prints `None` if "Fib" and the Factorial function won't break out of the loop.